# Присвоению столбцу тип данных DATEONLY sequilize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Мне нужно создать таблицу со столбцом year c типом данных DATEONLY(изначально таблица данных была создана с типом данных Integer, затем поменял). Но выводит ошибку:

```
столбец "year" нельзя автоматически привести к типу date
```

Как починить?

```
const Book = sequelize.define('book', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    author: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    vendorCode: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
    year: {type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: false},
    numberOfCopies: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER}
});
```

Comment: В каком формате хранятся данные в поле year?

Comment: изначально таблица создалась с типом данных Integer, я так понимаю пересоздание таблицы решит проблему?

Comment: Если данные из таблицы удалить, думаю оно и так сконвертируется. Проблема в данных, которые лежат в данном поле. Движок не может сконвертировать значение в дату